# How to pass both mandatory and optional command line arguments to perl script?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I am using Getopt::Long to pass options to my Perl script.

But I want to do something like this :

```
perl myScript mandatoryArgument1 -optionalArgument1=someValue
```

I want the script to throw an error if mandatoryArgument1 is missing. How can this be done?

Comment: You might find [this article](http://perltricks.com/article/195/2015/10/21/Professional-scripts-are-a-snap-with-Getopt--Long/) useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The good `Getopt::Long` does not have a mechanism for that. It specifically [processes *options*](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#GetOptions-does-not-return-a-false-result-when-an-option-is-not-supplied).

However, as it does its work it removes those options from `@ARGV` so once it's finished you can check whether the expected arguments are there. See the second part for this but I would like to first suggest another way: Make those arguments named and then `Getopt` will process them.

Then it is easy to check whether they were submitted.  For example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Getopt::Long;

my $mandatoryArg;
my $opt;

# Read command-line arguments, exit with usage message in case of error
GetOptions( 'name=s' => \$mandatoryArg, 'flag' => \$opt )
    or usage(); 

if (not defined $mandatoryArg) {
    say STDERR "Argument 'name' is mandatory";
    usage();
}

# The program goes now. Value for $opt may or may have not been supplied

sub usage {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 ...";   # full usage message
    exit;
}
```

So if `--name string` isn't given on the command line the `$mandatoryArg` stays undefined and the program exits. That variable doesn't need a default value since it is mandatory, and it shouldn't have one for this check to work.

Argument checking and processing is often far more involved, and this is when `Getopt` shines.

---

The `mandatoryArgument1` in the question is supplied without a name. While `Getopt` can be made to [act on a non-option input](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Argument-callback), it cannot detect that an expected one is *not* there.<sup>†</sup>

The module does allow to mix arguments with named options, anywhere on the command line. See [Option with other arguments](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Mixing-command-line-option-with-other-arguments) in docs. So you can invoke the program as

```
script.pl --opt1 value1 unnamed_arg --opt2 value2
```

but I'd suggest to the user to supply them after named options.

Then, after `GetOptions` does its job, `@ARGV` will contain the string `unnamed_arg` and you can get it (or find out that it isn't there).  Processing of named options by `GetOptions` is the same as above.

```
my ($var1, $var2, $flag);

GetOptions('opt1=s' => \$var1, 'opt2=i' => \$var2, 'f' => \$flag)
    or usage(); 

# All supplied named options have been collected, all else left in @ARGV
# Read the remaining argument(s) from @ARGV, or exit with message

# This can get far more complicated if more than one is expected
my $mandatoryArg1 = shift @ARGV || do {
    say STDERR "Mandatory argument (description) is missing";
    usage();
};
```

Above you have to process `@ARGV` by hand once `Getopt` picked up the named arguments.

If there is more than one such argument the user has to strictly respect their expected relative position on the command line, as there is in general no way for the program to tell what's what. So errors where the user confuses their order on the command line in general cannot be caught.

This becomes a hindrance and I'd suggest to have *at most one* kind of unnamed argument(s), and only in the case where it is obvious what that must be, like filename(s).

While all this is possible modules like `Getopt` exist precisely so that we don't have to do it.

---

<sup>†</sup>   Action for input that doesn't look like an option is set up using the "name" of `'<>'`

```
Getoptions( 'opt=s' => \$var, ..., '<>' => \&arg_cb );

sub arg_cb { say "Doesn't look like an option: $_[0]" }
```

where the sub `arg_cb` is invoked only if a non-option-looking argument *is seen*.

Answer (score 3):

My approach with `Getopt::Long`:

```
sub help { print "Some help"; exit }

sub main {
    GetOptions(
        'file|f=s'   => \( my $file = undef ),
        'tag|t=s'    => \( my $tag = undef ),
        'help|h'     => \( my $printHelp = undef ),
    );

    help() if $printHelp;
    help() unless $file;

[...]

}
```

In this case, the option `--file` or `-f` is mandatory. I check if `$file` is defined, otherwise I abort execution printing the help of the program.

I wouldn't mix *named* input parameters in the form `--param=*value*` with no-named parameters. 
That said, you can manipulate `@ARGV` before calling `Getopt::Long` and configure it to do what you have asked, but it is confusing to mix two types of input parameter *philosophy* for the users of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use Carp;
use Getopt::Long;    

sub main {    
    my $firstParam = shift @ARGV;
    croak "Mandatory parameter not given"
        if (!$firstParam || $firstParam =~ /^-/);

    GetOptions(
        'file|f=s'   => \( my $file = undef ),
        'tag|t=s'    => \( my $tag = undef ),
    );


    say 'Mandatory: ', $firstParam;
    say 'Optional $file: ', $file if $file;
    say 'Optional $tag: ', $tag if $tag;
}

main();
```

You can call it as `./test.pl mandatory -f file -t tag`:

```
Mandatory: mandatory                                                                                        
Optional $file: file                                                                                      
Optional $tag: tag
```

You will have to restrict the mandatory parameter(s) to a fixed position (in my example the first as in the question, but it could be the last ones also).