# Script does not die if there are incorrect arguments

Tags: perl, getopt

I'm quite new to the Perl programming. I want to use GetOptions to parse input arguments for my script. I have simple problem - I want script to exit with usage message if there's mess in arguments or arguments are missing values (for mandatory arguments). 
src_xml is mandatory argument but if I run the script not providing value for this argument, I get an error message about usage of uninitialized value $src_xml in -e at tenant_tenant.pl. What am I doing wrong? Or do I have to check every variable if its defined?

```
my $dev;
my $src_xml;
my $tgt_syscd = 'L86'; 
my $tgt_path = '/tmp/test/exports'; 
my $help;

GetOptions('src_xml=s' => \$src_xml,
        'tgt_syscd=s' => \$tgt_syscd,
        'tgt_path=s' => \$tgt_path,
        'dev' => \$dev,
        'h|help' => \$help
) or die "Usage: perl $0 --src_xml NAME --tgt_syscd NAME  --tgt_path NAME 
\n";

#checking for help
if ( defined $help ) {
    die $help_message;
}
```

Comment: See also [How to pass both mandatory and optional command line arguments to perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37453445/2173773)

Comment: Getopt::Long does not support mandatory options. You must check if it was changed from the value it started with, or you can use a custom subroutine to detect if an option was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will die only this way:

`perl ./foo.pl --src_xml=`

Check arguments with custom subroutine?

```
GetOptions(
    'dec-to-base35=i' => \&dec_to_base35,
    'base35-to-dec=s' => \&base35_to_dec,
);

sub dec_to_base35 ( $opt_name, $decimal_value ) {
...
```

Complete example [here](https://github.com/manwar/perlweeklychallenge-club/blob/master/challenge-002/maxim-kolodyazhny/perl5/ch-2.pl)

BTW, you can join ["Perl weekly challenge"](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/), this may help to learn something new